# Callback for d3 click event

Tags: d3.js

I've got an event listener for click:

```
circle.on('click', function() { ... });
```

Can I use a callback to do something after the click event handling has occurred?

Comment: What do you mean by "bind the event"?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Mistake with wording, updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but you can run arbitrary code inside the `click` handler, including code that is run after the "normal" event handling is done. You can also trigger other events from that code to allow you to use other callbacks.

Comment: What if I want to add a listener for a click event that has just occurred, I added the listener inside the on click handler but it fires the event from there. Hmm.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example? I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do.